# Changing the target framework from 4.5 to 4.0

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

In an .NetFramework application, why when, after changing the target framework from 4.5 to 4.0, the app still references 4.5 framework libraries?
Is there a way for solving this?

Answer (score 1):

[.NET 4.5 is a replacement for .NET 4.0.](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Mar/13/NET-45-is-an-inplace-replacement-for-NET-40) So, when you change the Target Framework, it will still use the files of .NET 4.5, because they replaced the files of .NET 4.0. But don't worry, when changing the Target Framework, your app should work perfectly on a computer where only .NET 4.0 (*not* 4.5) is installed.

Comment: In the application log I can see there are some libraries that still references .netframework 4.5. In this case are some entity framework references.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue right now, my develop pc has .NET Framework 4.5, and also I changed the proyect target framework to 4.5. I just belived this where a know common issue.